# Unable to deploy Maven WAR project to JBoss: The selection did not contain any resources that can be run on a server

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-tools

I'm using JBoss 7.1 AS, Eclipse Indigo, Maven 3.0.3 on a Mac OSX Lion.  I have successfully registered JBoss 7.1 as a local server within Eclipse.  I installed the JBoss tools for Eclipse, right clicked my Maven project, selected "Mark as deployable", but then the problem arises.  When I right click on "Run As" -> "Run on Server", I'm greeted with the error

```
 The selection did not contain any resources that can be run on a server
```

Any ideas what additional steps I should take to make this bad boy deploy?  Let me know what other information I should provide.

Comment: this can hardly be answered without some further details. How does your project look like? Can you run `mvn clean install` without errors? What packaging does you project specify in pom.xml(war, jar)? Do you have automatic build turned on in Eclipse preferences? Also , can you try to add it to Jboss from the _Servers_ view? In _Servers_ view, right click your Jboss instance, click _add or remove_ and add you project.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens to me when I'm dealing with Maven projects too.

Try the following: In Package Explorer right-click on your project pom.xml then use "Maven > Update project". After that you should click on menu "Project > Clean...".

Now try to add/remove again.

By the way, you should't need to mark your entire project as deployable under normal conditions.